# Azure App Configuration Values referencing other Keys

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-app-configuration

In Azure Devops Variable Groups you do something like:

FileRepo = 'FolderA'
LogFile = '$(FileRepo)/Log.txt'

Is this possible in Azure App Configuration?

*UPDATE:
When using the App Configration as an Azure Devops [Task extenstion](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AzureAppConfiguration.azure-app-configuration-task), $() references will work during pipelines.

Comment: May I know how's the progress going? Did Krzysztof Madej's answer solve your issue? Free to comment below if you still has any puzzle on it:-)

Comment: This is exactly what I was attempting to do! It's unfortunate that Microsoft hasn't added support for this feature, but like many seemingly common features I would expect to find (e.g. sorting tables by various columns) Azure just hasn't implemented them yet.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. Settings are flat and they do not support referencing to other settings values. You can try to do this programmatically, by replacing your tokens with real values, but there is nothing out of the box.

Comment: I found that using the App Configuration task in Azure Devops, it does correctly resolve the referenced settings. But I guess its the Devops Pipeline runtime that does that.

Comment: Yes, it applies references at runtime before updating App Configuration.